# Finding $Var\left({X\over Y}\right)$

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be discrete random variables such that

$\Pr[X=x,Y=y]=\begin{cases} \dfrac{3x+2y}{42} & x=1\,\text{ or }\,2,\quad{}y=x+1\,\text{ or }\,x+2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$\text{ Calculate }\,Var\left(\dfrac{X}{Y}\right)\text{.}$

I'm honestly not sure on how to do this. The $y=x+1 \text{ or } y = x+2$ is throwing me off.

I tried just plugging in $1$ for $x$ and got $P({X=1\over Y=2})$ but I'm not sure if this is what I'm suppose to be doing.

Comment: $x$ can take two values, and for each value of $x$, $y$ can take two values. (You should be able to determine those values.) You can then get the probabilities that (X,Y) takes a particular pair of values, and you can use this to compute the values of X/Y and the corresponding ptobabilities. This gives you the information you need to compute the variance.

Comment: @user3697176 I can plug in all of those values, but I don't get how to compute X/Y

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The probaility is non-zero only for $(x,y) \in \{  (1,2), (1,3), (2, 3), (2,4)\}$

Can you compute all the possible values for $\frac{X}{Y}$ and the corresponding probabilities?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to compute $X\over Y$ That is the issue.

Comment: @Heavenly96. If $(X,Y)=(1,2)$ then $\tfrac XY= \tfrac 12$ et cetera.

Comment: If $(X,Y)=(2,4), \frac{X}{Y} = \frac12$ as well, can you do so for $(1,3)$ and $(2,3)$ too?

Comment: Would I do $$E({X\over Y})={1\over 2}(P(X=1,Y=2)+P(X=2,Y=2))+{1\over 3}(P(X=1,Y=3)+{2\over 3}P(X=2,Y=3)$$ @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: @Heavenly96 And similarly $\mathsf E(\tfrac {X^2}{Y^2})$

Comment: @Heavenly96 yup, just a typo, $P(X=2, Y=2)$ suppose to be $P(X=2, Y=4)$.

Answer (score 2):

The support is $S=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4)\}$

Then by definition:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(X/Y) ~&=~ \mathsf E(X^2/Y^2)-\mathsf E(X/Y)^2 \\ & =~ \sum_{(x,y)\in S} (\tfrac xy)^2 \Pr(X=x,Y=y) - \left(\sum_{(x,y)\in S}\tfrac xy \Pr(X=x, Y=x)\right)^2\end{align}$$